# TypeError when trying to perform multiplication on array of integers

Tags: python

This bit is fine just makes sense to put it in

```
digit = input("input a 5 digit number:")
if len(digit)==5:
    digit = list(digit)
    print(int(digit[2]))
    print(int(digit[4]))
else:
    print("error")
```

Here I am trying to multiply the 2nd and 4th digit by 2

```
new_digit1 = int(digit[0]*"%d" %1)
new_digit2 = int(digit[1]*"%d" %2)
new_digit3 = int(digit[2]*"%d" %1)
new_digit4 = int(digit[3]*"%d" %2)
new_digit5 = int(digit[4]*"%d" %1)

printable_digit = new_digit1 + new_digit2 + new_digit3 + new_digit4 + new_digit5
```

The error:

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: What are you expecting `int(digit[0]*"%d" %1)` to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
digits = raw_input("enter your 5 digit number") # raw input will keep it as a string

digs = list(digits)
```

This line should be

```
new_digit2 = int(digit[1]*"%d" %2)
```

should be

```
new_digit2 = int(digit[1])*2
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` and `%` have the same precedence, regardless of what types they are used on. As such, `digit[0]*"%d"` is evaluated first, and the result used with `% 1`. You appear to be expecting `"%d" % 1` to be evaluated first, with that used as the multiplier (or multiplicand, no one can seem to agree which is which) along with `digit[0]`.

That is, `digit[0] * "%d" % 1` is equivalent to `(digit[0] * "%d") % 1`, and you are trying to multiply two strings together.

You need to use parentheses to force the desired evaluation order.

```
digit[0] * ("%d" % 1)
```

(I'm ignoring the question of why you aren't just multiplying each digit by the integer directly. There's not much need for the `%` operator here.)